# solr 5.1 deleted docs mergefactor and optimzations

Tags: indexing, solr

I am using solr 5.1 on a stand alone Box (Linux VM).

My scenario is :- I am indexing around 10 million documents per day  using solrnet, while 1000 docs spread around the day, rest 9+ million documents are done at a specific time and take around 4-5 hours to index.

Each document is around 6KB of size and physical memory of VM is 110GB.
Solr JVM is configured for 30GB

Is merge factor still a valid setting for 5.1 I read some where that it is obsolete now ?
should I use MMapfactory as of now it is NRTCachingDirectoryFactory?

The problem I am facing with all these settings are

```
a) Time outs some times(Get and Post)
b) Deleted docs not getting removed
```

Below are some of the solrconfig settings for improving query time and indexing time

```
        <ramBufferSizeMB>2048</ramBufferSizeMB>
        <maxBufferedDocs>2048</maxBufferedDocs>

        <mergeFactor>20</mergeFactor>

         <autoCommit> 
           <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
           <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
         </autoCommit>

        <autoSoftCommit> 
           <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:1800000}</maxTime>
          <maxDocs>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxDocs:500000}</maxDocs>
         </autoSoftCommit>

       <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"        
       class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}">

     <queryResultWindowSize>50</queryResultWindowSize>

   <!-- Maximum number of documents to cache for any entry in the
        queryResultCache. 
     -->
   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>50</queryResultMaxDocsCached>




  <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512"   
    autowarmCount="0"/>
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="2048" 
   initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="2048" initialSize="512"  
    autowarmCount="0"/>
```